# How to create an authentication system in django for a SQLServer database?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, authentication, visual-studio-code

I am recently working in a django project with a SQLServer database. I already connected the database with SQLServer, and I want to make an authentication system for a table I have in that database.

I know django comes with a built-in authentication system, but there is no way to tell django to use a specific table in the database to make the authentication, it just seems to look for users in the default admin page.

Is there any way for django to look for data inside a specific table in a SQLServer database and validate the information put by an user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by implementing you own user model and then telling django how to authenticate the user. Your model should look something like this:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
```

You can add extra fields, but those are required by django. The property is_authenticated shall always return true, as defined in the documentation.

Next step is to define how will your login authenticate. Create a file name backends.py anywhere in your project and inside of it declared two methods: authenticate and get_user, it should something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from users.models import Users
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import *
from login.util import *

class PersonalizedLoginBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request=None, username=None, password=None, **kwars):
        #Here define you login criteria, like encrypting the password and then
        #Checking it matches. This is an example:
        try:
            user = Users.objects.get(username=username)
        except Users.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        if check_password(password, user.password):
            return user
        else:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        #This shall return the user given the id
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
        try:
            user = Users.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except Exception as e:
            user = AnonymousUser()
        return user
```

Now you need to tell django that where is the backends located, on your settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # ... your other backends
    'path.to.backends.PersonalizedLoginBackend',
)
```

From there you should be able to do your login like normal, first authenticate and then use do_login function.

Read more details in here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/